# Check the various modes of Wi-Fi and mobile data Connection in Android

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, internet-connection, mobile-data

I want to write an event for different modes of Wi-Fi connection and mobile data.

1. If the Wi-Fi is on and the mobile data is off, the Wi-Fi icon will be visible
2. If the mobile data is on and the Wi-Fi is off, the mobile data icon will be visible
3. If both are on, both icons will be visible
4. If both are off, the icon will be gone
5. If both were on, and one of them went off, the icon that went off would go off

Exactly the same as the phone's system performance!
‍‍‍‍‍‍

```
public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifiType = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobileType = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifiType.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            wifi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (mobileType.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (wifiType.isConnectedOrConnecting() || mobileType.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            wifi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            wifi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            data.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify your code to work properly.

```
public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        assert connectivityManager != null;
        NetworkInfo[] activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : activeNetworkInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                   {
                    wifi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   } else if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                   { 
                    data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   }else {
            wifi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            data.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

make sure that you add this line to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I think also that you mistaken when you add this code:

```
 else if (wifiType.isConnectedOrConnecting() || mobileType.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            wifi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

It doesn't have any sense because you already test if one of them is connected so I suggest to change the code instead:

```
public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        assert connectivityManager != null;
        NetworkInfo[] activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : activeNetworkInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                   {
                    wifi.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   } else {
                      wifi.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                      }
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                  if (ni.isConnected())
                   { 
                    data.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   }
                 else {
            data.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```